# How to access router links one after the othe in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have router links, which I need to visit in a series like  one by one, (1 ->2 ->3 ->4 ->5 ->6)
and cannot go back from 6->1 3->2

in my app.js file code is like this:-

```js
class App extends Component {       
  render() {        
    return (           
      <HashRouter>        
       <nav className="nav">         
        <div>      
        <div className="content">
        <div class="donorTitle"><b>Donor Registration</b></div>  <br/>    
          <ul className="header">  
            <font size="18px" color="white"><li> <NavLink to="/"><img src={eligibilitypng}/></NavLink></li></font>
            <li> <NavLink to="/ValidateMobileNumber"><img src={validatemoilenumberpng}/> </NavLink></li> 
            <li> <NavLink to="/PrimaryInformation"><img src={primaryinformationpng}/> </NavLink></li>
            <li> <NavLink to="/DeclarationOfUnderstanding"><img src={declarationofunderstandingpng}/> </NavLink></li> 
            <li> <NavLink to="/ConsentForm"><img src={consentformpng}/> </NavLink></li> 
            <li> <NavLink to="/UniqueId"><img src={uniqueidpng}/> </NavLink></li>
          </ul>   
           <br/><br/><br/><br/>       
          <Route exact path="/" component={EligibilityCheck}/> 
            <Route path="/ValidateMobileNumber" component={ValidateMobileNumber}/>
            <Route path="/PrimaryInformation" component={PrimaryInformation}/>
            <Route exact path="/DeclarationOfUnderstanding" component={DeclarationOfUnderstanding}/>
            <Route path="/ConsentForm" component={ConsentForm}/>
            <Route path="/UniqueId" component={UniqueId}/>
          </div>     
        </div>      
        </nav>    
        </HashRouter>          
    );     
  }      
}          

export default App;
```

I have made various attempts at this in vain - comments and help are welcome.

Comment: You can restrict navigation with Prompt component based on the step data https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/preventing-transitions. or you can create a PrivateRoute auth style component https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow. can also wrap you links with withRouter and disable them according to the current location

Answer (score 0):

first, you need pass a state with your NavLinks:

```
 <NavLink to={location => ({ pathname: "/", state: { prevPath: location.pathname } 
        })}>eligibilitypng</NavLink>
```

now for every route change I will pass a state object to the location.

next you need to a special Route component:

```
function RestrictedRoute({ component: Component, restrictedPath, ...rest }) {
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={({ location }) => {
                // if url typed directly throw him back to the beginning
                return !location.state ? (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: "/"
                        }}
                    />
                   // if coming from the restricted path throw him back
                ) : location.state.prevPath === restrictedPath ? (
                  <Redirect
                    to={{
                      pathname: location.state.prevPath
                    }}
                  />
                // all is good
                ) : (
                    <Component />
                );
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

And the usage is:

```
                              <Route
                              exact
                              path="/"
                              component={() => 
                               <div>EligibilityCheck</div>}
                               />
                              <RestrictedRoute
                                path="/ValidateMobileNumber"
                                restrictedPath="/PrimaryInformation"
                                component={() => 
                                    <div>ValidateMobileNumber</div>}
                               />
                              <Route
                                path="/PrimaryInformation"
                                component={() => <div>PrimaryInformation</div>}
                              /> 
                              //...more routes
```

full code example:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    HashRouter,
    NavLink,
    Route,
    Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";

function RestrictedRoute({ component: Component, restrictedPath, ...rest }) {
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={({ location }) => {
                // if the user try to type /step2 in the browser url input directly throw him to step1 or where ever you want
                return !location.state ? (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: "/"
                        }}
                    />
                    // if the user comes from step 3 throw him back to step 3
                ) : location.state.prevPath === restrictedPath ? (
                  <Redirect
                    to={{
                      pathname: location.state.prevPath
                    }}
                  />
                  // access is grunted to the route
                ) : (
                    <Component />
                );
            }}
        />
    );
}



class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <HashRouter>
                <nav className="nav">
                    <div>
                        <div className="content">
                            <div className="donorTitle">
                                <b>Donor Registration</b>
                            </div>{" "}
                            <br />
                            <ul className="header">
                                    <li>
                                        {" "}
                                        <NavLink to={location => ({ pathname: "/", state: { prevPath: location.pathname } })}>step 1</NavLink>
                                    </li>
                                <li>
                                    {" "}
                                    <NavLink
                                        to={location => ({ pathname: "/step2", state: { prevPath: location.pathname } })}
                                    >
                                        step 2{" "}
                                    </NavLink>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    {" "}
                                    <NavLink to={location => ({ pathname: "/step3", state: { prevPath: location.pathname } })}>
                                        step 3{" "}
                                    </NavLink>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <Route
                                exact
                                path="/"
                                component={() => <div><h1>step1</h1></div>}
                            />
                            <RestrictedRoute
                                path="/step2"
                                restrictedPath="/step3"
                                component={() => <div><h1>step2</h1><p>can't go to here from step 3...</p></div>}
                            />
                            <Route
                                path="/step3"
                                component={() => <div><h1>step 3</h1></div>}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </HashRouter>
        );
    }
}



ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

*Note*: that you can reuse RestrictedRoute to any route you would like.

**Live code** [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jjytga)

Comment: Can you tell me as per the code fully.because i am new to this concept.thanks in advance

Comment: i am sorry, its was disabling only second, i.e 3->2. i want it as 3->2->1, and after clicking on  3 and everything must be disabled i.e 2 and 1. i need it urgently .........

Comment: hi ,  but according to my code i have router links which are routed to some other pages, so my question is where should i place my router links. ii  mean navlinks and route path. so please help me with according to my code. so that u can save my life.thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry Its an example  that works.The rest is up to you.Unless you wanna pay me by the hour :-)

Comment: sure i will pay for you, can u do me this task   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59709668/change-images-onclick-in-reactjs/59709842#59709842

Comment: An upvote for the effort I invested here will besufficient.thanks in advance.